# How do I disable a set of radio buttons when a radio button from another set is clicked

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

How do I disable the second set of radio buttons if the radio button on the first set is set to Yes? And enable if set to No?

First set:

```
<input type="radio" id="firstsetno" name="xfirstset" value="0" checked>No

<input type="radio" id="firstsetyes" name="xfirstset" value="1">Yes
```

Second set:

```
<input type="radio" id="secondsetno" name="xsecondset" value="0" checked>No

<input type="radio" id="secondsetyes" name="xsecondset" value="1">Yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know Jain answered this already but I figured I'd provide a solution that's slightly easier to read. I used jQuery (as did Jain) but you could accomplish the same thing using vanilla JavaScript if you prefer.

```
//Fire when the status of the radio button #firstsetyes changes
$("input[type=radio][name='xfirstset']").change(function() { 
    // Get the radio buttons in the second set
    var secondSet = $("input[type=radio][name='xsecondset']");

    for (var i = 0; i< secondSet.length;  i++){
        console.log(secondSet[i]);
    }

    if( $('#firstsetyes').prop('checked') ) {           
        // Loop through the second set and disable the buttons
        for (var i = 0; i< secondSet.length;  i++){
            secondSet[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i< secondSet.length;  i++){
            secondSet[i].disabled = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Here's also link to the CodePen where I wrote and tested the code: https://codepen.io/Rikkokiri/pen/OvpzYg?editors=1011

---

**Update**

To make second set default to 'no', you just need `checked` in your input tag corressponding to answer 'no' (like you had in your code, I just took it out while I was testing. I've now updated my pen in Codepen to have it.)

```
<form>
    <p>
    <input type="radio" id="firstsetno" name="xfirstset" value="0" checked>No
        <br>
<input type="radio" id="firstsetyes" name="xfirstset" value="1">Yes
        </p>
    <p>
Second set:
<br>
<input type="radio" id="secondsetno" name="xsecondset" value="0" checked>No
    <br>
<input type="radio" id="secondsetyes" name="xsecondset" value="1">Yes
</form>
```

---

**Update 2**

If you'd like it to just disable the 'no' button in the second set, instead of looping through all the buttons in the second set, you simply target the no button.

```
$("input[type=radio][name='xfirstset']").change(function() { 

    if( $('#firstsetyes').prop('checked') ) {           
        $('#secondsetno').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        $('#secondsetno').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, it worked. Thanks Rikkokiri! How can you make the secondset always defaulted to No and disabled everytime you click Yes on the firstset?

Comment: @francoom You are very welcome! I updated the answer so that it hopefully answers your additional questions. Feel free to ask more questions or clarifications if you need any.

Comment: Thanks Rikkokiri. When I clicked No on the first set and checked Yes on the second set, and then selected Yes on the first set, the second set was disabled but did not go back to the suppose-to-be defaulted checked No. It would be OK if it is not possible. Thanks :)

Comment: Also when the page loads, xfirstset is defaulted to Yes when the page loads, but xsecondset is not disabled, unless you click on the xfirstset No then back to Yes. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hello again. I was able to get the xsecondset always defaulted to "no" everytime xfirstset is checked to Yes by adding this on the condition:   `$('#performancedegradationno').prop('checked', true);`  I will just need help then on how the secondset will be disabled once the page loads because the first set is defaulted to Yes. Thanks much!!!

Comment: @francoom Well if you know that you want to always disable when the page loads (meaning you don't need to check whether 'yes' in first set is checked because you've set it to checked), then you can simply add $('#secondsetno').prop('disabled', true); to your document ready function.
If you want to check the first yes then just wrap that disabling line in condition if( $('#firstsetyes').prop('checked') ) {...} in your document ready.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Onload disable
$.each($("input[name='xsecondset']"), function(index, radio){
      $(radio).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});

$("input[name='xfirstset']").click(function(){
  $.each($("input[name='xfirstset']"), function(index, radio){
    if(radio.checked && radio.value === "0"){ 
     $("#secondsetno")[0].checked = true;  //reset to default      
       $.each($("input[name='xsecondset']"), function(index, radio){
      $(radio).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
       }
       if(radio.checked && radio.value === "1"){              
       $.each($("input[name='xsecondset']"), function(index, radio){
         
      $(radio).removeAttr("disabled");
    });
       }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="firstsetno" name="xfirstset" value="0" checked>No

<input type="radio" id="firstsetyes" name="xfirstset" value="1">Yes

<input type="radio" id="secondsetno" name="xsecondset" value="0" checked>No

<input type="radio" id="secondsetyes" name="xsecondset" value="1">Yes
```

```
// Onload disable
$.each($("input[name='xsecondset']"), function(index, radio){
                     $(radio).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});

$("input[name='xfirstset']").click(function(){
        $.each($("input[name='xfirstset']"), function(index, radio){
             if(radio.checked && radio.value === "0"){  
                $("#secondsetno")[0].checked = true;  //reset to default            
                $.each($("input[name='xsecondset']"), function(index, radio){
                     $(radio).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                });
             }
             if(radio.checked && radio.value === "1"){                          
                $.each($("input[name='xsecondset']"), function(index, radio){

                     $(radio).removeAttr("disabled");
                });
             }
        });
    });
```